# How to get Ubuntu VM on GitLab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to move my post-installation scripts from GitHub+Travis to GitLab. To test these scripts, I use the trusty build environment with Travis CI to get a bare Ubuntu VM rather than run the script in a container. I am wondering if there is a way to do this with GitLab CI.

So far, I have been able to get a Debian VM from a public shared runner by adding the `linux` tag to my `.gitlab-ci.yml`. However, this presents some obvious issues when installing software assumed to be in the ubuntu repositories. Is there an equivalent to the `dist: trusty` in Travis in GitLab?

My `.travis.yml`:

```
dist: trusty                                                                                            
language: python                                                                
notifications:                                                                  
email: false                                                                  

env:                                                                            
  - TEST_RUN="bash ubuntu-std-install.sh"                                       
  - TEST_RUN="bash ubuntu-server-install.sh"                                    

script: "$TEST_RUN"
```

My `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
stages:
  - build

server-build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - bash ubuntu-server-install.sh
tags:
  - linux

std-build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - bash ubuntu-std-install.sh
tags:
  - linux
```

Comment: Maybe you need a image: ubuntu:trusty, but this is for using a trusty docker image. If you want to use a real VM, you can install gitlab runner on machine mode if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use docker executor (or shell) with `image:trusty`. 
Or if you need any special dependencies for the build you can create your own docker image and you can use it, like `image: foo/myimage`.

Also you can run your own gitlab-runner from your preferred operation system.